# is it possible to use a v-for in vue for non-array objects from a json file?

Tags: node.js, json, vue.js

i am trying to pass some values from a json file to a component however i keep getting "product is undefined"

product.json

```
{
    "product": {
        "price": 1.11,
        "amount": 0.11
    }
}
```

component in vue js:

```
<div v-for="prod in product" :key="price">
```

How can i get rid of this error?

Comment: For using `v-for` you should use array. So the product should be an array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined `product` in the data of your Vue instance, you could use it within the v-for.

I've included a working version in the fiddle below.

```js
let productJson = {
    "product": {
        "price": 1.11,
        "amount": 0.11
    }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return productJson;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(value, key) in product">{{key}}: {{value}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need to loop over the keys of the object.

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for this.

```
<div v-for="prodKey in Objects.keys(products)" :key="products[prodKey].price">
```